# How to correctly perform a JdbcQuery that have a date as where condition?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working on a Spring application using **JdbcTemplate** and I have the following doubt:

I have to implement a method that perform the following simple query:

```
select * from CoefficienteRendimento 
where DataRendimento = '2015-08-01 00:00:00'
```

where the value of the **DataRendimento** field can change.

So I am doing something like this:

```
public BigDecimal getRendimentoLordoCertificato(XXX) {

    String sql = "select * from CoefficienteRendimento where DataRendimento =  ?";

    .......................................................................
    .......................................................................
    .......................................................................


}
```

So my doubt is:

for this sitatuon is better to pass as **XXX** parameter (that have to be used inside the query) a String value as **'2015-08-01 00:00:00'** or a **Date** object representing this date?

Comment: Generally spoken it is better to use a Date, because you do not need to convert anything, which could go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

```
Date yourDate = ...
Connection conn = ...

String sql = "select * from CoefficienteRendimento where DataRendimento =  ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setDate(1, yourDate);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    ... // Handle your resultSet
}
```

---

Updated answer knowing that the result should be a single (at most) BigDecimal and that Spring JDBC is used.

Using jdbcTemplate, and knowing that there are 0 or 1 results, and you like to get a valid result or `null`:

```
public BigDecimal getRendimentoLordoCertificato(Date currentDate) {

    String sql = "select Coefficiente_12 from CoefficienteRendimento where DataRendimento =  ?";

    List<BigDecimal> rendicontoLordoCert = getJdbcTemplate().query(
            sql, new Object[] { currentDate }, BigDecimal.class);

    if (rendicontoLordoCert.size > 0) {
        return rendicontoLordoCert.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by explicit specifying the date in pareparedStmt.

```
ps.addValue("yourDate", new java.util.Date(), java.sql.Types.DATE);
```

Comment: addValue is not a method of PreparedStatement

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring **JdbcTemplate** class so the solution is:

```
public BigDecimal getRendimentoLordoCertificato(Date currentDate) {

    String sql = "select Coefficiente_12 from CoefficienteRendimento where DataRendimento =  ?";

    BigDecimal rendicontoLordoCert = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
            sql, new Object[] { currentDate }, BigDecimal.class);

    return rendicontoLordoCert;

}
```

Comment: Why returning a BigDecimal if the questionnair was asking for an int?

Comment: Because working on my code I disover that the coumn on the DB contains a decimal value and not an integer

Comment: So the question was wrong. If so correct also the question, so eventual additional answers will be corrected

Comment: note that queryForObject needs always 1 result. If you pass a date that has no results your code will generate an exception

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Tnx, I will handle this situation :-)

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Tnx so much :-)